# Comparison of make and nmake for perl module installation

Tags: windows, linux, perl, makefile, nmake

Module installation varies when compared to Windows and linux/Unix Operating system.

In  Win32 we need to use a program called **nmake** and after we follow

```
 1. C:\> perl Makefile.PL 
 2. C:\> nmake
 3. C:\> nmake test
 4. C:\> nmake install
```

and in Linux we follow

```
 1. $ perl Makefile.PL
 2. $ make
 3. $ make test
 4. $ make install
```

the process of installing would be same for both the operating systems, the only difference would be in the keyword used **make** and **nmake**. Could any one let me know what does the letter ***`n`*** represents and what is its specification in windows.

Comment: Whether you use nmake, make, or dmake depends on the setup, even within Windows.  A default tool-chain for Strawberry Perl includes dmake.  nmake is commonly included with the ActiveState distribution's tool-chain, and under cygwin, I suspect you would have 'make' (though I haven't used cygwin to confirm).  ExtUtils::MakeMaker generally creates a makefile that will fit the lowest common denominator with respect to the common 'make' implementations, so unless you're really getting fancy, you shouldn't have to worry except to worry about whether or not user actually has some version of make.

Comment: @DavidO, Cygwin is a unix emulation layer, so calling it Windows is like saying WINE is linux. `cygwin` provides GNU tools, so it uses GNU's `make`.

Comment: :) I like the analogy, @ikegami.  You're correct, of course.  I was just hedging out of uncertainty with how the platform is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29),

> Microsoft nmake, commonly available on Windows. It is fairly basic in
>   that it offers only a subset of the features of the other two versions
>   of Make (BSD and GNU ). Microsoft's nmake is not to be confused with
>   nmake from AT&T and Bell Labs for Unix.

Microsoft `nmake` is detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and GNU `make` is detailed [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, module installation is usually done as follows on Windows and linux:

```
cpan Module::Name
```

---

On to your question.

Perl expects the same compiler suite that was used to build Perl to be used to build the module.

There are two primary tool chains on Windows. There is the one provided by Microsoft and there is a port of GNU's.

- The make tool provided by Microsoft is named `nmake`.
- The make tool provided by the MinGW port of GNU's tools is named `dmake`.

So,

- If your Perl was built using MS's tools (e.g. Windows builds of Perl by ActiveState), you need to to use `nmake`.
- If your Perl was built using GNU's tools (e.g. builds of Perl by Strawberry), you need to to use `dmake`.

---

Which brings us back to `cpan Module::Name`.

`cpan` will ask Perl what tools were used to build it, and use those tools.

Normally. That's not the case on Windows. `cpan` is actually far more flexible on Windows. `cpan` will first look the tool chain that was used to build Perl. If it's not found, `cpan` install the GNU tool chain for you and temporarily fool `perl` into believing it was built using GNU's tool chain.

That means you run `cpan Module::Name` it should work no matter what on ActivePerl. (And there's also `ppm install Module::Name`, although I'd run `ppm` with no arguments first to add repositories (e.g. bribes))